# How to draw circles at equal distance relative to another circle

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, shapes, interface-design, page-layout

I'm pretty bad at Photoshop and I need to draw 5 smaller circles at equal distance of one another, around another a bigger circle.

How can I do that?

[image: photo]

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1** - Align your big circle and small circles to the center of the canvas to have a simple reference point (since we know exactly what the center of the canvas is).
[image]

**Step 2** - Move all of your small circles to the desired distance from the big circle.  Then select four of them and enter free transform mode (Ctrl+T).  If your reference point is disabled, check the box to enable it.
[image]

Set the X and Y for the reference point to the center of your big circle.  Since we aligned to the center of the canvas, we know this is exactly half the width and height.  For me it was 2400x3000.  Note: for some reason I also had to alt-click on the canvas to be able to set my reference point via the entry fields.

Set the rotation to 72 degrees (360 divided by 5).

**Step 3** - Deselect one of your circles and press Shift+Ctrl+T to Transform Again.  Repeat until done.
[image]

**Step 4** - If you need to adjust the position, select all of the small circles, set the reference point again, and rotate.

Comment: That's how I finally chose to do it and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This applies to Illustrator, assuming you also have that installed. It probably works in Photoshop as well, but Illustrator is better & quicker for this and gives you a sharper, vector format result:

1. Create the big and small circles one next to each other and vertically aligned (initial circles in green)
2. Connect exact centers using a line (use outline mode and/or snap to point) (pink line)
3. Group pink line with the small circle
4. Duplicate 4 times, rotate by 360/5=72 degrees
5. Move each of these copies to snap the very center of the big circle
6. Ungroup all, remove pink lines and clean up

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great, in-detail answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest you don't use Photoshop for work like this, even though you could use it.  It's really not the right kind of software for creating geometric shapes/logos.

It's much easier and better to use vector software such as Illustrator or Inkscape for a graphic like the example. It can be created using a simple duplication and rotation transform around a circle.

In Inkscape, for example, you can draw circles, snap the rotation point to the centre of another circle

Duplicate (CTRL+D), and apply a 72° rotate transform and repeat.

[image]

Comment: I think I will use Inkspace rather than Illustrator because it is a freeware. Thanks:)